# How can I request for a pdf of a book on academia.edu?

Tags: academic-life

How can I request for a new document or pdf on academia.edu.Will academia find it for me?

Comment: Why not try the publisher?

Comment: If you can find the author's email address, then I suggest you ask the author directly.